# Can I refer to those certificates as Qualification certificates?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

I have qualified some exams. Now I need to send those certificate to a recruiter. Can I refer to those certificates as *Qualification certificates*?

Comment: If you are looking for work, you are selling a candidate with every element. If qualified means you passed exams, do you really want to say send Passing Certs? Maybe Examination Certificates, maybe look at the paper and see what it calls itself.

Comment: It is rather unclear what it is to qualify some exams. One may pass an exam, or one may do sufficiently well on an exam to qualify for something else.